# I want to update database by adding +1 but its not working

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to update my database but its not working please help. 
Suppose i have current point (10 points) I want to Add 1 points, but it changes the current point (10 points) to 1.
Not adding 10 to 1 = 11

```
$points = $user_home->runQuery("UPDATE tbl_users SET spoints = 'spoints' + 1 WHERE userID=:uid");
$points->execute(array(":uid"=>$_SESSION['userSession']));
```

Comment: Try removing the `'` in `'spoints'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must remove the quotes around the field name or use backticks like this:

```
SET spoints = `spoints` + 1

OR 

SET spoints = spoints + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:
`` $points = $user_home->runQuery("UPDATE `tbl_users` SET spoints = spoints + 1 WHERE userID=:uid"); ``

Answer (score 0):

You're using ' instead of ` therefore it'd be:

```
$points = $user_home->runQuery("UPDATE `tbl_users` SET `spoints` = `spoints` + 1 WHERE `userID` = :uid");
$points->execute(array(":uid"=>$_SESSION['userSession']));
```